# React-Native WebView previous button app does not work on the IOS

Tags: react-native

webview app done with react-native works in android with its Hardware previous button key but doesnt work in IOS . Is there anybody to know about this problem ?

Comment: iOS doesn't support hardware backpress like android

Comment: I understand. Too bad. So how do I proceed if I put a in back button?